# Laravel - ForeignIdFor() Cascade not Deleting the Related Data

Tags: php, laravel

I have just recently using foreignIdFor() in laravel instead of foreign() because it makes simple on development. However, when delete the data it wont delete the related data. Even though, I have set cascade there

Here is the migrations file

```
    Schema::create('agency_listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignIdFor(Agency::class,'agency_id')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
        $table->foreignIdFor(AgencyAgent::class,'agency_agent_id')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
        // $table->unsignedBigInteger('agency_agent_id');
        // $table->foreign('agency_agent_id')->references('id')->on('agency_agents')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
        $table->foreignIdFor(Listing::class,'listing_id')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->index(['created_at','updated_at']);
    });
```

I have set cascadeOnDelete and cascadeOnUpdate but its not working. When I use simple foreign() it deletes the data. The main problem I have converted all the foreign() to foreignForId() in all my migrations. I appreciate any helps. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To someone who face the same problem, we need to set constrained() then add cascade method after it.

```
    Schema::create('agency_listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignIdFor(Agency::class,'agency_id')->constrained('agencies')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreignIdFor(AgencyAgent::class,'agency_agent_id')->constrained('agency_agents')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreignIdFor(Listing::class,'listing_id')->constrained('listings')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->index(['created_at','updated_at']);
    });
```

Hopefully someone could post the more readable code, I have no idea what is the purpose of settings the model while we need to specify which table. I thought it is automatically define the constrained()

Comment: It's nothing to do with table names. You didn't have `constrained()` in your original migration at all.

Comment: You also don't need to specify the column name, it will be determined automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, appreciate it